# How do I read these sets of notes?

Tags: sheet-music

I came across this sheet music pdf in the link of a YouTube video and I can't understand what these notes are. Can someone explain how one reads and plays the notes ( on a guitar) in the red box and blue box?[image]

Edit: what are the brackets surrounding the circled head of 8th note?

Answer (score 0):

In the red box, two independent voices are notated, but on guitar you may play both simultaneously in harmony.

The blue box is also two independent voices but both voices are on the same note. On guitar you may just consider them single notes. Perfect unisons are possible on guitar but they are usually a stretch when out of context.

The bracketed notes are a ghosting of the first phoneme /th/ in they. The notation indicated its tone is indeterminately lower when compared with the next, standard note.

Comment: So for the notes in the red box, I just play the Gand D notes together? And the blue box is just playing the F note?

Comment: Yes that is how I would go about playing those.

Comment: I would add one thing to this.  Sometimes in classical guitar pieces a unison is indicated for a note that matches an open string.  In this case you can play the fretted note and the open string at the same time.  Clearly in this case that is not possible.  This is not a guitar piece, this is vocals on harmony.